# Unclickable FloatActionButton

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a custom widget what includes a 3 FloatActionButton-s and I can't understand why my 3rd FAB is not pressed over the whole area, onPressed triggered only when I click on bottom of this button.

MyState build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 2.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: edit(),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: delete(),
        ),
        add(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Edit button - have the looking like code with others 2 buttons but problem appears only with click on this one:

```
Widget edit() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _editButtonVisible,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        heroTag: 'edit',
        onPressed: () {
          print('edit');
        },
        tooltip: 'Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.edit),
      ),
    );
  }
```

It's my Animation, and interested point - if I change `end`, for example, to -4 it will reduce space between FABs and my button will be clickable on the whole area..

```
_translateButton = Tween<double>(
      begin: _fabHeight,
      end: -14.0,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.0,
        0.75,
        curve: _curve,
      ),
    ));
```

So I think maybe cause is size of column?
Left picture with bad working button and right with stable one. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Their is two way to solve your problem.
1) if you have only four elements in list as found in your screenshot then you can use column attribute 
mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.min

2) use stack widget

Comment: Hi, MainAxisSize didn't help, what do you mean by stack widged? List doesn't matter.. https://github.com/Sc4pego4t/notes/blob/master/Screenshot_1535646284.png

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by wrap my `Column` with Container what have fixed height)
Now my code looks like:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
              0.0,
              _translateButton.value * 2.0,
              0.0,
            ),
            child: edit(),
          ),
          Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
              0.0,
              _translateButton.value,
              0.0,
            ),
            child: delete(),
          ),
          add(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```